# UriComponentsBuilder/UriComponents encode doesn't behave correct

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc

i have following code (package org.springframework.web.util)

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("/test/").queryParam("rt","http://a.com?u=1").build(false).encode().toUriString()
```

actual result:
/test/?rt=http://a.com?u%3D1

what i expected is:
/test/?rt=http%3a%2f%2fa.com%3fu%3d1

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, `UriComponentsBuilder` doesn't encode the query parameters automatically, just the original `HttpUrl` it's instantiated with. In other words, you still have to explicitly encode:

UriComponentsBuilder is encoding your URI in accordance with RFC 3986 (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt, in particular section 3.4 which is about the 'query' component of a URI).

Within the `query` component, the characters `'/' and ':'` are permitted, and do not need escaping.

To take the `'/'` character for example: the `query` component (which is clearly delimited by unescaped `'?'` and (optionally) `'#'` characters), is not hierarchical and the `'/'` character has no special meaning. So it doesn't need encoding.

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("/test/").queryParam("rt",URLEncoder.encode("http://a.com?u=1", "UTF-8")).build(false).encode().toUriString();
```

output : /test/?rt=http%253A%252F%252Fa.com%253Fu%253D1

Comment: thanks. but you can see, UriComponentBuilder still does something like "encoding". It changes '=' to '%3D'.